# Count properties of an object

Tags: powershell

I try to count the number of drives on certain `VM's` in a Cluster:

```
(Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster <Name> | 
    Where-Object {$_.GroupType –eq 'VirtualMachine'} | 
    Get-VM | 
    Measure-Object -Property Harddrives).Count
```

> --> Returns 55, the count of `VM's` in the Cluster

Several VM's have more than one Harddrive, how can I retrieve the proper Count of Drives in a pipelined command?

Answer (score 3):

Try enumerating the property:

```
$harddrives = Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster '<String>' | ? GroupType -eq VirtualMachine |
        Get-VM | % HardDrives
$harddrives.Count
```

---

Some shorthand in v4+:

```
(@(Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster '<String>').
    Where({ $_.GroupType -eq 'VirtualMachine' }) |
    Get-VM).HardDrives.Count
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much. I was fuzzling around with the where-object, but didn't know the -filterScript option.

Comment: @MMAX: Your own code uses the `-FilterScript` parameter too, only _positionally_. What makes this answer work is the explicit enumeration of the `.HardDrives` property, which `Measure-Object` doesn't do.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem that was closer to the original question.  I had a custom PowerShell object that I needed to *literally* count how many properties were in it.  I found this:

```
($Object | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Measure-Object).Count
```

Comment: Thanks! this was what I was actually looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To *complement* [TheIncorrigible1's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51212707/45375), which contains an effective solution but only hints at the problem with your `Measure-Object` call:

Perhaps surprisingly, `Measure-Object` *doesn't enumerate* input objects or properties that are *themselves* collections, as the following examples demonstrate:

```
PS> ((1, 2), (3, 4) | Measure-Object).Count
2  # !! The input arrays each counted as *1* object - their elements weren't counted.

PS> ([pscustomobject] @{ prop = 1, 2 }, [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 3, 4 } | 
      Measure-Object -Property prop).Count
2  # !! The arrays stored in .prop each counted as *1* object - their elements weren't counted.
```

---

The above applies as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.1.0.
[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7244) suggests introducing a `-Recurse` switch that would allow opting into enumerating collection-valued input objects / input-object properties.